# VS - vb file got corrupted - Unexpected token & Character is not valid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

After launching my project in VS2019, I suddenly got a Character is not valid error, and I was not able to run my project anymore.

I didn't change anything.  I even did some undo's just to be save, but no luck.
The error remained, and it didn't point me anywhere.

I restarted VS and then it even got worse.
I couldn't see my code anymore.  I just see question marks, and 6995 errors, all (unexpected token and character is not valid).

[image]

I tried several things, including deleting the .suo file, the settings file.
Restarting the pc and so on.
Sadly enough the "Previous Version" history of Win10 is switched off, so I can't go to a recent backup.

If I click on the designer he gives me the folling error message:

[image]

If I continue, I see my designer file in the end.

[image]

When I double click on a button, to try and see the code, he gives me new code in the designer file.  Which is really strange.

[image]

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: This is a perfect example of why even a hobbyist should be using source control. If you were, you could simply revert your code to the last committed state and away you go. Start using source control ASAP. There are various options available, with Azure DevOps and Github being two that offer free accounts and VS integration. Not only do you get automatic offsite backup and related features, it means that you can sync your development on multiple machines, which is very useful for quite a few people.

Comment: As for the issue, it's hard to say exactly what's happened and whether there is a way to revert it. It could be an encoding issue or who knows what. With source control, a few clicks would fix it. As it stands, I think that you're just going to have to rebuild it manually. This is why backups are so important. Learn from this.

Comment: The error suggests that VS2019 doesn't have an editor for .vb files. Maybe some part of VS got corrupted somehow. Try a repair install or even uninstall/reinstall. Before going any further though take a backup copy of all the project files. Have you tried opening any of the .vb files in a text editor to see if the contents are actually corrupt or just that VS can't understand them?

Comment: It is just 1 file which is corrupted, and when I open that with notepad++ I see the same thing as in VS.   Sometimes I can see the last part of the code, while the first part remains in question marks.  It is so strange.

Comment: You might need to open it in a hex editor and make sure that the contents are exactly what you expect.  My recollection is that Visual Studio uses UTF-8, so you would expect to see a format mark at the very start of the file.  After that, make sure that you don't see anything outside of the expected range. For typical English-language development, everything should be alpha, parens, and typical operator characters, but the VS languages do support Unicode identifiers which might come into play for non-English-language development.